# preg_replace_callback with anonymous function

Tags: php, eval, anonymous-function, preg-replace-callback

I'm getting this error, but I cannot find out why:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\test.php(19) : eval()'d code on line 1`

Any insight would be appreciated!

```
$table = '<table><tr><td>${Q*10}</td></tr></table>';

$symbols = array('Q' => 10);

preg_replace_callback('/\${(\w+)([*+-\/])(\d+)}/', function($matches) use ($symbols, $table) {
    return repl($matches, $symbols, $table); 
}, $table);

function repl($tokens, $symbols, $table)
{
    $replace = array_shift($tokens);

    $operand1 = $symbols[$tokens[0]];
    $operator = $tokens[1];
    $operand2 = $tokens[2];

    $val = eval("$operand1 $operator $operand2");
    // Fix: $val = eval("return $operand1 $operator $operand2;");

    $table = str_replace($replace, $val, $table);

    echo $table; // Should be 100
}

// EOF
```

Comment: You really should use something like a `switch` statement instead of `eval`. Also, you should escape the hyphen in `[*+-\/]`. Inside `[]` it means *from `+` **to** `\\`*. You can also put it as the last character in the brackets. Further more, seeing as you are use math operators the first and last captures should be numbers only, i.e `\d+` instead of `\w+`.

Comment: Thank you for the regex comment. I will probably end up using a `switch` -- I thought the problem was with my anonymous function, not the eval.

Comment: The first operand is really just an index for my `$symbols` array, but the second operand will always be a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`eval`](http://php.net/eval) needs to contain a statement or block of statements, not just an expression.

To actually get the result and assign it you need:

```
    $val = eval("return $operand1 $operator $operand2;");
```

As @ggutenberg said, at the very least the semicolon to eschew the syntax error. But the `return` to do what you intended to do.

<s>The `$matches` list will contain the complete string at position `[0]`. The capture groups start at `[1]`. You might need to adapt the `$tokens` assignment in your callback.</s>

Comment: This suggestion made my code work. Also, I use `array_shift` in my `repl` function

Comment: Okay, get it now; was confused about your `$replace` variable. But you appearantly echo it right back instead of returning the altered string result to preg_replace_

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a semicolon to the end of your eval string.

Comment: This suggestion made the error go away, but mario's answer was more complete.